# Safe deleting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, sql-delete

I am trying to delete table rows using custom table valued function in where clause.

Like this :

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM MYFUNCTION(DATE));
```

My function selects records from tables with some unions. It intended that this function must return some rows. I had no problems with it. Until one case where all rows have been deleted. After investigation i came to conclusion that function should return something.
Are there any cases when function could return nothing e.g. When SQL Server is performing some tasks (Backup, Any validation, restoring any other databases)

The last test showed that if pseudo function returns any `NULL` or NULL with results e.g. `(1,NULL,5)` absolutely nothing gets deleted.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You've posted a fairly standard delete statement - do you not think that the interesting part to your code/problem might be the code of the function?

Comment: It is just straightforward select statement used in the function. It always worked well.

Comment: I would reverse the logic - create a function that returns the list of items to delete. That way, if the function doesn't return anything, nothing gets deleted. Also: typically you probably want to delete a few percent of your rows - listing these should be much easier and faster than listing all those that you **don't** want to delete...

Comment: It is the solution to remove records more safely.

Comment: @Mchood: And yet the delete query you've posted is perfectly fine. If nothing has changed in your function, then I would think something has in your data or, possibly, metadata.

Comment: Actually in that time some other databases potentially were in restoring state on same server.

Comment: @mchood - post your function code.

Comment: Without tables to play with its difficult to see what the problem might be. What does `SELECT * FROM [Vikarina].[PAGADA] (NULL)` return? If nothing is there any possibility that your calling code can pass `NULL`?

Comment: @Martin: I have tested the function by locking tables, editing records in them and calling the function at the same time. It always returned results as expected or exception because of table locks was thrown. I have never seen NULL returned by this function.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, when NULL passed to function it returns NULL. But there is no possibility to pass NULL to function.

Comment: "It is the solution to remove records more safely" by `delete`ing everything unless explicitly excluded? This is not "more safe" by most people's definition. Is your situation more threatened by existent data than it would be by missing data?

Comment: Please show the contents of the function. Anything without this is meaningless speculation.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any cases when function
>   could return nothing e.g. When SQL
>   Server is performing some tasks
>   (Backup, Any validation, restoring any
>   other databases)

Although it's possible that any dbms might do something like that, changing behavior because other tasks are running would be a huge, flaming, critical bug. It would be so widely publicized it would be hard to miss the news.

Have you ever heard the saying, "When you hear hoofbeats, think 'horses', not 'zebras'"? It's far more likely that the hoofbeats you hear are a bug in your code than a bug in their code.

My guesses would be a misplaced paren, an isnull() test that returns something you didn't expect, unexpected NULL propagation, or an error in date arithmetic. You seem to have a lot of nullable columns.

This expression looks suspicious.

```
Dateadd(DAY,-2,Dateadd(MONTH,1,@prad)
```

Comment: @Catcall This expression is OK.

Comment: @Catcall This `Dateadd(DAY,-2,Dateadd(MONTH,1,@prad)` expression is OK. It works as should. If ISNULL doesn't work as expected it is their bug.

Comment: @Mchood: I meant that isnull() might be either finding a null where you didn't expect one, or isn't finding a null where you did expect one. Or, perhaps, that something you were certain could never be null acutally is. (There seem to be a lot of nullable columns.)

Comment: @Catcall: It is hard to believe that problems are with NULL's. This function have been implemented 3 years ago. It is widely used with no problems. Until one case on "Microsoft SQL Server 2008" few weeks ago. We have never had problems with it on "Microsoft SQL Server 2005".

Comment: @Mchood: Can you load current data into SQL Server 2005 and run the same procedures? If it fails, the problem is definitely in the data, not the code.

Comment: @Catcall: Actually after data loss function worked well as before it. And yes with same data it works well even on "Microsoft SQL Server 2008".

Comment: @Mchood: Can you load the troublesome data into SQL Server 2005? (The data that led directly to your function returning no rows.)

Comment: @Catcall: Function with troublesome data works perfectly on both server versions (2005-2008).

Comment: @Mchood: Does that mean you can't reproduce the problem?